# hash objects containing string properties in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashmap

I need to make a custom class as key in my dictionary.
Which method is used by C# to do hashing when key is string?

```
internal class Patient:IEquatable<Patient>
    {
        public string fname{ get; set; }
        public string lname{ get; set; }
      

    
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(fname+lname);

        }

    }
```

Is this the correct approach (concatenation and generating hash), or is their any better way to generate hash.

Comment: What would the result of `Bobb Yvan` vs `Bobby Van` be? :-)

Comment: You may want to change the properties to be init only instead of settable. Latter changing those properties will change the hash and those objects will be lost in containers like dictionaries. So prevent later change.

Comment: If there is a chance of collisions (two different Patient objects having the same fname and lname), you might need to consider additional properties to include in the hash code calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Since .NET Core 2.1 you can use [`HashCode.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode.combine?view=net-6.0):

```
return HashCode.Combine(fname, lname);
```

Or for case insensitive version:

```
return HashCode.Combine(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(fname),
    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(fname));
```

Comment: Prior .NET Core 2.1 : `return new { fname, lname }.GetHashCode();`